# Win7 Built-in Text Editor with File Change Notify

Tags: windows-7, text-editors, notifications, text-editing

Is there any built-in software that will allow me to view a text file but will also notify me if the text file I am editing/viewing is changed by another process?  There are third-party solutions for this (Visual Studio, Notepad++), but I'm looking for something that comes with Windows 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing within windows itself which will accomplish this.  The closest you can come is to write a windows scheduled task to check the files last modified date on a timer and notify you if there is a change then.